# Why SuperPuTTY needs ALT+TAB+TAB to switch to other window in Win 10

Tags: superputty

Behavior is very similar to [Why do I have to hit tab twice to Alt+Tab away from Microsoft Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1088782/why-do-i-have-to-hit-tab-twice-to-alttab-away-from-microsoft-excel) it is just related to [SuperPuTTY](https://github.com/jimradford/superputty).

I need to hit alt+tab+tab to switch to other application. Even if I have multiple tabs opened, there is just one PuTTY in task bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will find why in this issue comments: https://github.com/jimradford/superputty/issues/216

It seems that Windows sees both SuperPUTTY and the Putty inside it as two separate applications: the first alt+tab moves you from Putty to SuperPUTTY, the second tab from SuperPUTTY to the next application.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that's an issue I experienced.